# How to get the average of a column?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a query something like this:

```
SELECT id, cat_id, avg_position, site, date
FROM X
WHERE site = 'com'
AND id = 18
AND date = DATE('2020-03-02')
```

When I run the query, I basically want to see the average of avg_position for each id, cat_id, and site. But somehow I am getting different avg_position values even all other columns are the same each other.

It seems that avg_position is grouped by a column that I did not select it.

What am I missing? What's the way to get the average value of avg_position?

Here is the query with average of avg_position, but it returned to zero with this query:

```
SELECT id, cat_id, AVG(avg_position) as pos_avg, site, date
FROM X
WHERE site = 'com'
AND id = 18
AND date = DATE('2020-03-02')
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_AVG.html

Comment: AVG function does not work, unfortunately. The output returned to zero.  @Zeljka

Comment: Please add your query with AVG to question

Comment: It seems that avg_position is grouped by a column that I did not select it. @elvira.genkel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AVG aggregate function

```
SELECT id, cat_id, AVG(avg_position), site, date
FROM X
WHERE site = 'com'
AND id = 18
AND date = DATE('2020-03-02')
GROUP BY id, cat_id, site,date
```

Please do not forget to group results by all the fields that are not under aggregation

Comment: It again returned to zero. The type of variable of avg_position is double. Does it help us to understand why?

Comment: Oh, when I add the date in group by, it worked now. :) Thanks!

Comment: Ooops, sorry, i've missed date in my answer. Added now.